# Tranform origin not working as it should with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, mouseevent

I am trying to create a ripple effect on a link acting as a button, and I want the ripple to take effect from the point where the mouse enters the button. However, it doesn't capture the coordinates the time when the mouseenters and uses the ones from the previous event.
This behavior is baffling me as it should update the property instanteneously.
Here is my code

HMTL

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="www.gotohell.com" class='button ripple'>
        <span></span>
        Live fullest!
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 32px;
}
.ripple {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.ripple > span {
    border-radius: 32px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .3s ease;
    z-index: -1; 
}
.ripple:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

JS

```
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
const ripple = document.querySelector(".ripple > span");
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
    let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    let x = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
    let y = e.clientY - rect.top; //y position within the element.
    ripple.style.transformOrigin = x + "px " + y + "px";
    ripple.style.transform = "scale(1)";
});
button.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
    ripple.style.transform = "scale(0)";
});
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong!

Tried various methods of getting the coordinates of the pointer where it enters the button, they work fine but the transform origin does not update until the next event.

Comment: Have you tried running this without the `let` inside the `mouseenter` callback? As in `x = e.clientX... ; y = ...`?

Comment: @biinster that almost certainly will not help; there's nothing in the code posted that requires those variables to be relatively global to the event handler.

Comment: yes binster.  I tried declaring them globally too, behavior was same

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
const ripple = document.querySelector(".ripple > span");

let timer;
let x, y = 0;

button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
  clearTimeout(timer);

  let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  x = e.clientX - rect.left; // x position within the element.
  y = e.clientY - rect.top; // y position within the element.

  ripple.style.transformOrigin = x + "px " + y + "px";
  ripple.style.transform = "scale(1)";
});

button.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
  ripple.style.transform = "scale(0)";

  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    ripple.style.transformOrigin = "initial";
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.ripple {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.ripple>span {
  border-radius: 32px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}

.ripple:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="www.gotohell.com" class="button ripple">
    <span></span> Live fullest!
  </a>
</div>
```

---

**Explanation:**

The problem with your code was that after the first try the span element had the same value of `ripple.style.transformOrigin` as the previous try because you never reset its value. Hence the animation started from the previous position.

Your code before the first try: (the span is in center)

[image]

Your code after the first try: (span remains at the position where the mouse enters)

[image]

`setTimeout` of `300ms` here is used assuming you wanted the animation to end where it started, to give time for the animation to end.

If that is not the case and you want the animation to start where the mouse enters and end at the center then you can just to this:

```js
button.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
  ripple.style.transform = "scale(0)";
  ripple.style.transformOrigin = "initial";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying panda, however, the problem still persists. What I want is the transform origin should update the values as soon as the mouse enters the button and should start scale animation from that point of origin. It ends on that point but not originates.